# Python set docstring and get method name of dynamically generated classmethod

Tags: python, decorator, class-method, python-decorators, docstring

I'm trying to get/set the name and docstring of dynamically created class methods as follows, but am having trouble figuring out exactly how to do it:

```
import sys
import inspect

class test(object):
    pass

@classmethod
def genericFunc(cls, **kwargs):
    print "function:", (inspect.stack()[0][3])
    print "kwargs:", kwargs

function_list = ['myF1', 'myF2']
for func in function_list:
    setattr(test, func, genericFunc)
    #set docstring for func here?

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = test()
    print "docstring:", x.myF1.__doc__
    x.myF1(arg1="foo")
    y = test()
    print "docstring:", y.myF2.__doc__
    y.myF2(arg1="foo", arg2="bar")
    sys.exit()
```

Currently the output is:

```
docstring: None
function: genericFunc
kwargs: {'arg1': 'foo'}
docstring: None
function: genericFunc
kwargs: {'arg1': 'foo', 'arg2': 'bar'}
```

What I'd like to have is:

```
docstring: description of myF1
function: myF1
kwargs: {'arg1': 'foo'}
docstring: description of myF2
function: myF2
kwargs: {'arg1': 'foo', 'arg2': 'bar'}
```

In the for loop I tried doing `setattr(test.func, "__doc__", "description of %s" % func)`, which resulted in an AttributeError exception (type object 'test' has no attribute 'func'), and if I hard-code 'test.myF1' instead of 'test.func' I get an AttributeError for attribute `'__doc__'` of 'instancemethod' not being writable.

Finally, the inspect.stack() returns "genericFunc" instead of a dynamic function name ('myF1' or 'myF2'), is it possible to get/set the latter so that I can check the value of the method's `__name__` within genericFunc to perform certain actions depending on its value?

Answer (score 1):

Your generic function itself doesn't have a docstring.  This works fine for me when I add a docstring:

```
    import inspect

    class test(object):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def genericFunc(cls, **kwargs):
        """ I'm a docstring"""
        print "function:", (inspect.stack()[0][3])
        print "kwargs:", kwargs

    function_list = ['myF1', 'myF2']
    for func in function_list:
        setattr(test, func, genericFunc)
        #set docstring for func here?

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        x = test()
        print "docstring:", x.myF1.__doc__
        x.myF1(arg1="foo")
        y = test()
        print "docstring:", y.myF2.__doc__
        y.myF2(arg1="foo", arg2="bar")
```

Also, why sys.exit() at the end?  As a result, I get:

```
docstring:  I'm a docstring
function: genericFunc
kwargs: {'arg1': 'foo'}
docstring:  I'm a docstring
function: genericFunc
kwargs: {'arg1': 'foo', 'arg2': 'bar'}
```

Comment: corerct, but that docstring would be static/the same for myF1, myF2 and any other functions I add to the function_list.  I'd like the docstring to be dynamic and incorporate the function name.  The sys.exit() is unnecessary, just a habit.

Comment: Is something like this not sufficient:

print "docstring:", x.myF1.__name__ + x.myF1.__doc__

Comment: `x.myF1.__name__` returns "genericFunc", not "myF1" or "myF2".  And I need to be able to get that value from within generalFunc.