# Accessing class attributes docstring for argparse

Tags: python, argparse, docstring

I am currently using argparse in a class much like this:

```
class MyClass:

  P_OPT = "my-opt"
  """This is an option to my script."""

  P_OPT_HELP = "This is an option to my script"
  """Description for argparse"""

  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      # do stuff here
      pass

  @classmethod
  def parse_arguments(cls):
      parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
      parser.add_argument('--' + cls.P_OPT, help=cls.P_OPT_HELP)

def main():
    MyClass(**MyClass.parse_arguments())
```

Works fine, but I have a lot of options and arguments, there is redundancy between the `P_OPT` docstring and the content of `P_OPT_HELP`. Also I have to make a docstring for `P_OPT_HELP` too otherwise my project linter will remain unhappy. [PEP 224](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0224/) decided that there would be no built-in way to get to class and instance attributes docstring at runtime.

Is there a module or a clever python trick to do this ?

What I am considering so far is just using `dict`, it does not prevent the redundancy but does not pollute my class namespace so much:

```
P_OPT = {"name": "my-opt", "help": "This is an option to my script"}
"""This is an option to my script"""
```

And then:

```
parser.add_argument('-' + P_OPT["name"], help=P_OPT["help"])
```

Comment: You could try this possible duplicate solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26145319/6529424

Comment: This thread concerns dynamical docstrings on functions, but thanks !